# How do I add an if , else if, else condition to my arrow function which includes .map and .filter already?

Tags: javascript, arrays, if-statement, arrow-functions, array.prototype.map

Below is a function that needs to set the option.value of a selected element inside the options array. It needs to set it  to $1.50 each if 3 or more options selected, and if 6 or more are selected it needs to be 1.00 each. Right now it works like a charm as it simply takes the options.value from the array and sets it to it's current price, however I need to add this discount functionality to my function. How can I achieve this?

My current working function without discount condition.

```
private getSelectedOptions(options) {
      return (options || []).filter(x => x.selected).map
         (option => ({ name: option.name, value: option.value || 0 }));
 }
```

Options array

```
 "options": [
    {
      "name": "Red Pepper",
      "selected": false,
      "value": 2.00
    },
    {
      "name": "Garlic",
      "selected": false,
       "value": 2.00

    },
    {
      "name": "Cheese blend",
      "selected": false,
       "value": 2.00
    },
     {
      "name": "pineapple",
      "selected": false,
       "value": 2.00
    },
     {
      "name": "bacon",
      "selected": false,
       "value": 2.00
    },
    {
      "name": "green pepper",
      "selected": false,

    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Save the mapped array in a variable first so you can check its `length` to identify the price needed:

```
private getSelectedOptions(options) {
  const selectedItems = (options || []).filter(x => x.selected);
  const price = selectedItems.length >= 6
    ? 1
    : selectedItems.length >= 3
      ? 1.5
      : 2;
  return selectedItems.map(
    option => ({ name: option.name, value: option.value ? price : 0 })
  );
 }
```

```js
const getSelectedOptions = (options) => {
  const selectedItems = (options || []).filter(x => x.selected);
  const price = selectedItems.length >= 6
    ? 1
    : selectedItems.length >= 3
      ? 1.5
      : 2;
  return selectedItems.map(
    option => ({ name: option.name, value: option.value ? price : 0 })
  );
};
 
 const options = [
  {
    "name": "Red Pepper",
    "selected": true,
    "value": 2.00
  },
  {
    "name": "Garlic",
    "selected": true,
     "value": 2.00

  },
  {
    "name": "Cheese blend",
    "selected": true,
     "value": 2.00
  },
   {
    "name": "pineapple",
    "selected": false,
     "value": 2.00
  },
   {
    "name": "bacon",
    "selected": false,
     "value": 2.00
  },
  {
    "name": "green pepper",
    "selected": true,

  }
];

console.log(getSelectedOptions(options));
```

If options can have different values, figure out a factor to multiply them by instead, like `1` or `0.75` or `5`:

```js
const getSelectedOptions = (options) => {
  const selectedItems = (options || []).filter(x => x.selected);
  const factor = selectedItems.length >= 6
    ? 0.5
    : selectedItems.length >= 3
      ? 0.75
      : 1;
  return selectedItems.map(
    option => ({ name: option.name, value: option.value * factor })
  );
};
 
 const options = [
  {
    "name": "Red Pepper",
    "selected": true,
    "value": 5.00
  },
  {
    "name": "Garlic",
    "selected": true,
     "value": 2.00

  },
  {
    "name": "Cheese blend",
    "selected": true,
     "value": 2.00
  },
   {
    "name": "pineapple",
    "selected": false,
     "value": 2.00
  },
   {
    "name": "bacon",
    "selected": false,
     "value": 2.00
  },
  {
    "name": "green pepper",
    "selected": true,

  }
];

console.log(getSelectedOptions(options));
```

Comment: The second ternary that sets the price to 2 could break the code, if the options either dont have the starting value of 2 or dont even have the same value.

Comment: Thank you so much. This is no doubt the right answer. I just have one last add on if you will. Since I am using the option.value in another function in my project, is there anyway to convert that price variable into the option.value after it has run through the conditional statment?

Comment: @evan Do you want a multiplying factor instead? See second snippet

Comment: Yes that works! your insight has brought up another problem that I may have regarding this issue., but at least I am much further along. I may be able to figure the rest out on my own. What remains is, I will have to have another condition to this function because the size of the pizza determines the ration between option.value and factor.

Comment: +1 for both the OP and the answer. In your first snippet, in the ternary, instead of the value 2 you could also put undefined, and then instead of `value: option.value ? price : 0` you could write `value: option.value && price ? price : option.value ? option.value : 0` to have the default price in case there are less than 3 selected and if not all starting prices are 2, or get 0 if options.value was not set for that element.

Answer (score -1):

Arrow Function is a normal JavaScript function, so, if you remove the "()" and just put "{}" turn into a function, with body, to return an object again, `return {}`